# stuck in using Megam in Python ( nltk.classify.MaxentClassifier)

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, nltk

I'm using ubuntu x64, after two days and searching all the net, still i've not been able to install Megam,
i've read all information in this page http://www.cs.utah.edu/~hal/megam/
and installed x64 version of o'calm from http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ocaml
but when i want to use "megam" as a classifier in python, it says:

> "NLTK was unable to find the megam file! Use software specific
>   configuration paramaters or set the MEGAM environment variable.

could anybody tell me how can i install and make use of it in python?

i've downloaded "`ocaml-3.12.1.tar.gz`" but the "make" command doesn't work (as it's said in its readme).
i've downloaded "`megam_i686.opt`" too, but it's not executable and i cannot run it

any help?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use config_megam() to tell NLTK where the Megam executable is located. See: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.classify.megam-module.html for details and documentation.

You also need to build MEGAM with the right 32/64 bit setting for your system. "megam_i686.opt" is for x86 iirc, so you should compile it for 64 bit. It is a while since I did this, but a simple build on an x64 system was all I needed: "Make doesn't work" is not very useful: I'm sure it gave you a few error messages...? Probably paths not set or are read only?

---

Edit: Looks like the above link is currently broken. The main Megam site can be found at:

http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/megam/

although it hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: @light-blue hey can you post directions on how you got the megam to work?

Comment: Hello @winwaed can you provide new link the existing link is no more active. thanks

Answer (score 9):

For the future users:

megam is now available on MAC through brew:

```
$brew tap homebrew/science
$brew install megam
```

Comment: but after installing it , I got another problem : `Exception ignored in: <generator object find_file_iter at 0x1060d1360> RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit optimizing with lambda = 0`

Comment: @zhuguowei Had similar error message. Problem resolved itself. Waited for a few minutes (2-3) and the process eventually finished. (Note: was using jupyter notebook).

Answer (score 2):

Answer given by Hugh Perkins, helped me resolve the issue (due to low reputation can't add a comment to that answer). After downloading the zip file (from http://thinknook.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MEGAM.zip), I needed to tell python where it was, and that was done by adding it in os.environ as:

os.environ["MEGAM"] = '<<Complete path followed by file name>>/megam-64'

Comment: Worked for me as well on a Fedora 29 VM !

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded from http://thinknook.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/MEGAM.zip , which was linked from http://thinknook.com/nltk-megam-maximum-entropy-library-on-64-bit-linux-2012-11-27/  This worked ok for me, on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I manged to get megam to run on my docker instance running debian 9.7 following the  steps below. Based on steps for MacOS install steps suggested by Jack Hong [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nltk-users/k3T6BzAsOJc).

1. apt-get install make
2. apt-get install ocaml-nox (or apt-get install ocaml, if you want x window support)
3. download source from [here](http://hal3.name/megam/megam_src.tgz)
4. unzip source creating a megam_0.92 directory
5. Edit the Makefile in megam_0.92 and make the following changes. (The
   first change was already done in my particular instance):

   - WITHCLIBS=-I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/caml
   - WITHSTR =str.cma -cclib -lcamlstr
6. Save the changes and run make inside your megam_0.92 directory
7. add nltk.config_megam('//megam_0.92/megam') to your script and all should be well.