# NLTK MEGAM - OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/Jag/Downloads/MEGAM/megam-64'

Tags: python, nltk

I'm doing the NLTK tutorial (http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) but got stuck at where it uses the Megam algorithm due to first not finding it. Did some searches and found this [stuck in using Megam in Python ( nltk.classify.MaxentClassifier)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071901/stuck-in-using-megam-in-python-nltk-classify-maxentclassifier) which I followed (i.e. at first I got the same error message '..unable to find the megam file! ...' as in that post) but now I receive the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/Jag/Downloads/megam_i686.opt'
```

Anyone have a clue of what that can be? Some searches for 'Exec format error' hints that it can be wrong file start (shebang) but the .opt file is in some strange encoding which I can't read.